# How to use Decimal, without putting to much pressure on computing in Python.

Tags: python, performance, parameters, decimal

I use linear regression gradient to calculate parametrs for my model, while using floats for linear model i had about 200 iterations per second which was ok. But since i use gaussian model i started to getting errors about float isn't enough anymore, so i rewrite the code completely using decimal module.

```
import decimal
decimal.getcontext().prec = 28
```

but when i calculate those parametrs i got something like

```
a = Decimal('-3.351803999105655683642509191E+5355')
```

which makes around 3000 iterations per 8 hours. Apparently i cant use such slow code. And i dont need SUCH precision in my calculations. I cant use floats with decimals - cos they dont work together creating a lot of errors if i try. How do i make it use less digits for calculations? Any tips for that kind of problem?

Comment: If you don't need such precision, why not try setting a lower precision? If speed is important, maybe try something like `numpy`?

Comment: Are you using python 3.3 or greater?  If not, the `cdecimal` module on pypy is faster than the builtin `Decimal` module: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cdecimal

Comment: 1. How would numpy would help me with this? Please explain!
2. I use Python 2.7.4.
3. As far as i can get i could use "quantize" but since my code is really huge and full of different equations - its hard to believe i had to apply it on every decimal i have.